# Como Fazer Merge 2 SELECT statements

Tags: php, mysql, merge

Como unir estes **2** `selects`?

MINHAS TABELAS

```
   EVENT  TITLE DESCRIPTION CATEGORY_ID 
   CATEGORY NAME COLOR ICON DESCRIPTION
```

esta select abaixo funciona perfeitamente faz o count certinho eu preciso      fazer o mesmo sem count nas outras duas selects

```
  SELECT category.*,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM event 
  WHERE category_id = category.id)as total FROM category
```

Ja tentei desta maneira

```
  "SELECT category.* FROM event WHERE category_id = 4) 
   FROM category ORDER BY MONTH(date_at)DESC "
```

Na outra Tabela

```
    SELECT * FROM event WHERE DATE(date_at) = CURDATE()

   "SELECT category.* FROM event WHERE category_id = 5) 
   FROM category ORDER DATE(date_at) = CURDATE() "
```

Consegui assim

```
SELECT  *, color
     FROM event , category 
    WHERE  event.id = event.category_id ;
```

soh não consegui colocar o  WHERE DATE(date_at) = CURDATE()

ALguem ?

Comment: Você vai precisar nomear as colunas se elas não forem iguais.

Comment: Eles possuem os mesmos campos com os mesmos tipos, poderia disponibilizar o layout e quais campos vão compor as duas SQL?

Comment: Qual o resultado vc espera pra essa consulta? A quantidade de eventos pra uma categoria especifica junto com as informacoes da categoria?

Comment: @carloscoelho tem como colocar as duas tabelas na sua pergunta e indicar o seu comentário também na pergunta?

Comment: Não precisa colocar em caracteres maiúsculos, isso parece estar gritando !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta isso:

```
SELECT 

c.NAME,
c.COLOR,
c.ICON,
c.DESCRIPTION,
count(e.DESCRIPTION) as count_evt

FROM category c
join event e on e.category_id = c.id

group by 
c.NAME,
c.COLOR,
c.ICON,
c.DESCRIPTION;
```

Comment: testei mas nao retorna nehum echo nao sei porque to precisando fazer isso aqui funcionar ele entra na categoria pega as cores e pega o title da tabela event   tentei este aqui mas nao deu "SELECT category.* FROM event WHERE category_id = 4) 
   FROM category ORDER BY MONTH(date_at)DESC "